# How do I change the MySQL database directory?

Tags: mysql, centos

I am using CentOS with cPanel. On my server, all MySQL databases save at `/var/lib/mysql`. Now `/var` is 100% full and MySQL has stopped working. How can I move the databases to a new directory like `/home/mysql` especially considering that this server is managed with cPanel?

Comment: Note that some versions of MySQL require you to modify the `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/homedir.conf` file to allow the DBs stored in the /home directory. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/#systemd

Answer (score 7):

I can't confirm this from cpanel, as I don't have access, but this is an example from the console connected by ssh and sudo to root. There are arguments for using a bind entry in /etc/fstab instead of a symlink, but this works for me.

My normal procedure is to stop mysql, move the directory contents, link the original, and restart mysqld.

```
[tomh@workstation001 ~]$ sudo su -
[root@workstation001 ~]# 

[root@workstation001 ~]# service mysqld stop
Stopping mysqld (via systemctl):  
                                                           [  OK  ]

[root@workstation001 ~]# mv /var/lib/mysql/ /opt/

[root@workstation001 ~]# ln -s /opt/mysql /var/lib/


[root@workstation001 ~]# ls -la /var/lib/mysql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Feb 26 23:02 /var/lib/mysql -> /opt/mysql

[root@workstation001 ~]# service mysqld start
Starting mysqld (via systemctl):                           [  OK  ]


[root@workstation001 ~]# mysql -uroot 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.5.18-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

mysql> show databases;
...
| Database              |
+-----------------------+
| information_schema    |
| mysql                 |
| performance_schema    |
| test
```

I just noticed a similar question, of which this is close to a duplicate of, which mentions some issues of doing that above with selinux enabled;
http://crashmag.net/change-the-default-mysql-data-directory-with-selinux-enabled

So if you have selinux there are some additional steps.

Comment: After follow these steps i try to start ten i got this error 
root@ns1 [/var/lib]# service mysqld start
mysqld: unrecognized service 
When i replace mysqld by mysql then output is as follow
root@ns1 [/var/lib]# service mysql start
Starting MySQL. ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.

Comment: What version of centos and mysql-server do you have and where did you get it? the base repos package for centos 5 and 6 call the service mysqld...

Comment: update your question with the output of `ls -lh /etc/init.d` and `ls -lh /var/lib/mysql` and `ls -lh /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: I was linking `/var/lib/mysql` to the new `data_dir` to lazy manage the default `mysql.sock` but recently I figure that it's not a good idea because socket and symlink is bad. So just `mkdir /var/lib/mysql` and `chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`, MySQL will create its socket and voila.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to change `mysql` data directory, you should do edit the mysql config file and change `datadir` value.

```
datadir = /home/user/data
```

Your new data directory **MUST** be owned by `mysql` and has proper SELinux security context.

```
chown -R    mysql:mysql /home/user/data
chcon -R -t mysqld_db_t /home/user/data
```

Then restart the `mysql` server:

```
systemctl restart mysql
# or
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Comment: pstump forgot to mention that you also need to shutdown mysql and copy all your data files to the new location before starting it up again.

Comment: Note that the official syntax of `chown` is `user:group` while `user.group` is an undocumented feature. I've changed that.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-MariaDB-Configuration_Examples.html) step by step guide working for me.

**You must install:**

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
```

**Guide:**

View the SELinux context of the default database location for mysql:

```
~]# ls -lZ /var/lib/mysql
drwx------. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
```

This shows `mysqld_db_t` which is the default context element for the location of database files. This context will have to be manually applied to the new database location that will be used in this example in order for it to function properly.

Stop the mysqld daemon:

```
~]# systemctl stop mariadb.service
```

Create a new directory for the new location of the database(s). In this example, /mysql/ is used:

```
~]# mkdir -p /mysql
```

Copy the database files from the old location to the new location:

```
~]# cp -R /var/lib/mysql/* /mysql/
```

Change the ownership of this location to allow access by the mysql user and group. This sets the traditional Unix permissions which SELinux will still observe:

```
~]# chown -R mysql:mysql /mysql
```

Run the following command to see the initial context of the new directory:

```
~]# ls -lZ /mysql
drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0   mysql
```

The context usr_t of this newly created directory is not currently suitable to SELinux as a location for MariaDB database files. Once the context has been changed, MariaDB will be able to function properly in this area.

Open the main MariaDB configuration file `/etc/my.cnf` with a text editor and modify the `datadir` option so that it refers to the new location. In this example the value that should be entered is `/mysql`:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/mysql
```

Save this file and exit.

Start `mysqld`. The service should fail to start, and a denial message will be logged to the `/var/log/messages` file:

```
~]# systemctl start mariadb.service
Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status postgresql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

However, if the audit daemon is running and with him the `setroubleshoot` service, the denial will be logged to the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file instead:

```
SELinux is preventing `/usr/libexec/mysqld` "write" access on /mysql. For complete SELinux messages. run `sealert -l b3f01aff-7fa6-4ebe-ad46-abaef6f8ad71`
```

The reason for this denial is that *mysql* is not labelled correctly for MariaDB data files. SELinux is stopping MariaDB from having access to the content labelled as `usr_t`. Perform the following steps to resolve this problem:

Run the following command to add a context mapping for *mysql*. Note that the `semanageutility` is not installed by default. If it missing on your system, install the `policycoreutils-python` package.

```
~]# semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/mysql(/.*)?"
```

This mapping is written to the `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local` file:

```
~]# grep -i mysql /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local

/mysql(/.*)?    system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0
```

Now use the `restorecon` utility to apply this context mapping to the running system:

```
~]# restorecon -R -v /mysql
```

Now that the *mysql* location has been labelled with the correct context for MariaDB, mysqld starts:

```
~]# systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Confirm the context has changed for *mysql*:

```
~]$ ls -lZ /mysql
drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
```

The location has been changed and labelled, and `mysqld` has started successfully. At this point all running services should be tested to confirm normal operation.

Comment: This is by far the best explanation for this problem I have encountered so far!

Answer (score -1):

Stopping the Default Install/Instance

```
service mysqld stop
```

Clear Current Config

```
rm /etc/my.cnf
```

Uninstal the Default Install/Instance

```
yum remove mysql mysql-server -y
```

Clear Current Datadir

```
test -d /var/lib/mysql/ && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
```

Clear the 'New' Datadir

```
test -d /mysql/mysql/ && rm -rf /mysql/mysql/
```

Install it again

```
yum install mysql mysql-server -y
```

Check the service status

```
service mysqld status
```

Start it - just to create a first/default structure

```
service mysqld start
```

Check the service status

```
service mysqld status
```

Interrupt the current MySQL server installation

```
service mysqld stop
```

Ensure that you don´t have anymore instance/service running

```
ps axu | grep mysql
```

Move the mysql data directory to '/mysql' partition and create the symbolic link

```
test -d /var/lib/mysql/ && mv /var/lib/mysql/ /mysql/ && ln -s /mysql/mysql /var/lib/
```

Check symbolic link and the real path

```
ls -lrth /var/lib/ | grep mysql
```

Set permission on new Datadir

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /mysql/mysql
```

Start it

```
service mysqld start
```

Try to connect (keep in mind that the default install of MySQL doesn´t set a 'pwd' for 'root' user and then you should connect with 'blank password'

```
mysql -u root -p --host 127.0.0.1
```

Once connected to MySQL, create a new db just to test if it´s working and where MySQL will create folder/file structure

```
create database DBTesteNew;
exit
```

Check if the new db is on the 'new datadir'

```
ls /mysql/mysql
```

Make sure the mysqld is set to start on boot time

```
chkconfig mysqld on
```

restart

```
reboot
```

Comment: Link - only answers are frowned upon. Please provide content *here* and link elsewhere for details if needed.

Comment: Getting there....perhaps try another whack at formatting things properly?

Comment: Hangs and will not start if I change the data-dir with the permissions on the dir correct.  Change it back to its default dir, and it starts fine.   Try using a symlink in /var/lib pointing to the "real data folder" and will not start. Try copying its default data-dir (created on install and works in /var/lib) to the new location - either pointing to it with config, or leaving default config and symlinking - will not start.  I do not want my data in /var in the system partition - so how to change the location and get it to start?  Uninstalled/reinstalled at least 6 times now.